# Laravel - How to retain the datepicker filter value after submit

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8, I use JQuery-UI datepicker to filter the table:

Controller:

```php
    public function leaveReport(Request $request)
    {
        if (! Gate::allows('hr_leave_report_access')) {
            return abort(401);
        }
    try{
        $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
        $method = $request->method();

        if ($request->isMethod('post'))
        {
            $from = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $request->input('from'));
            $to = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $request->input('to'));
            if ($request->has('search'))
            {
                // select search
                $searchReports = DB::table('hr_leave_requests AS lr')
                        ->join('hr_leave_types AS lt', 'lr.leave_type_id', '=', 'lt.id')
                        ->join('hr_employees AS em', 'lr.employee_id', '=', 'em.id')
                        ->where('lr.leave_status', 4)
                        ->where('lr.company_id', $userCompany)
                        ->whereBetween('lr.commencement_date', [$from, $to])
                        ->select('em.employee_code',DB::raw("CONCAT(em.first_name,' ',em.last_name) as full_name"),'lr.commencement_date','lr.resumption_date','lr.no_of_days','lt.leave_type_name')
                        ->get();
                return view('reports.leaveReport',[
                                            'searchReports' => $searchReports,
                                            'from' => $from,
                                            'to' => $to
                                            ]);
            }
            elseif ($request->has('exportPDF'))
            {
                // select PDF
                $pdfReports = DB::table('hr_leave_requests AS lr')
                    ->join('hr_leave_types AS lt', 'lr.leave_type_id', '=', 'lt.id')
                    ->join('hr_employees AS em', 'lr.employee_id', '=', 'em.id')
                    ->where('lr.leave_status', 4)
                    ->where('lr.company_id', $userCompany)
                    ->whereBetween('lr.commencement_date', [$from, $to])
                    ->select('em.employee_code',DB::raw("CONCAT(em.first_name,' ',em.last_name) as full_name"),'lr.commencement_date','lr.resumption_date','lr.no_of_days','lt.leave_type_name')
                    ->get();
                $pdf = PDF::loadView('reports.leaveReportPdf', ['pdfReports' => $pdfReports])->setPaper('a4', 'landscape');
                return $pdf->download('HR-LeaveTakenByDate-Report.pdf');
            }
        }
            elseif($request->has('exportExcel'))
            {
                // select Excel
                return Excel::download(new LeaveExport($from, $to), 'hr-leave-reports.xlsx');
    //            {
            }
        else
        {
            //select all
            $searchReports = DB::table('hr_leave_requests AS lr')
                    ->join('hr_leave_types AS lt', 'lr.leave_type_id', '=', 'lt.id')
                    ->join('hr_employees AS em', 'lr.employee_id', '=', 'em.id')
                    ->where('lr.leave_status', 4)
                    ->where('lr.company_id', $userCompany)
                    ->whereYear('lr.commencement_date', date('Y'))
                    ->select('em.employee_code',DB::raw("CONCAT(em.first_name,' ',em.last_name) as full_name"),'lr.commencement_date','lr.resumption_date','lr.no_of_days','lt.leave_type_name')
                    ->get();
                 //   dd($searchReports->toSql());

            return view('reports.leaveReport',['searchReports' => $searchReports]);
        }

        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            Log::error($exception);

            Session::flash('error', 'Action failed! Please try again');
            return back();
        }
    }
```

This is the view blade:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  // $(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $('.fromDate').datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      showAnim: 'slideDown',
      duration: 'fast',
      yearRange: new Date().getFullYear() + ':' + new Date().getFullYear(),
    });
  });
</script>
```

```html
<form action="{{route('reports.leaveReport')}}" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  @csrf
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <label for="from" class="col-form-label">From:</label>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
          </div>
          <input type="text" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" readonly autocomplete="off" name="from" value="{{$from}}" class="form-control fromDate">
        </div>
      </div>
      <label for="from" class="col-form-label">To:</label>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
          </div>
          <input type="text" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" readonly autocomplete="off" name="to" value="{{$to}}" class="form-control fromDate">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="search">Search</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" name="exportPDF"> <i class="fa fa-file-pdf"></i> Download as PDF</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" name="exportExcel"> <i class="fa fa-file-excel"></i>Download as Excel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Route:

```
Route::get('reports/leaveReport', 'LeaveReportsController@leaveReport')->name('reports.leaveReport');
Route::post('reports/leaveReport', 'LeaveReportsController@leaveReport')->name('reports.leaveReport');
```

I am using `JQuery UI datepicker` and `commencement_date` for `$from` and `$to`.

When I submitted the form with the search button, the values in the JQueru-UI datepickers ($from and $to) are cleared.

1. How do I retain these values
2. When the date fields are empty and the user submits, it throws error.

   #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor
   esbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Traits\Creator.php(645): Carbon\Carbon::rawCreateFromFormat('d-m-Y', NULL, NULL)

   #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\app\Http\Controllers\Report\LeaveReportsController.php(135): Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', NULL)

How do I resolve these?

Thanks

Comment: your question in not quite clear. you want to set values in `from` and `to` input fields with the values before submitting the form??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply pass it either as the GET parameter or pass the values from Controller to your view and use it like

Controller

```php
if ($request->isMethod('post'))
{
    $from = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $request->input('from'));
    $to = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $request->input('to'));
    if ($request->has('search'))
    {
        // select search
        $searchReports = DB::table('hr_leave_requests AS lr')
            ->join('hr_leave_types AS lt', 'lr.leave_type_id', '=', 'lt.id')
            ->join('hr_employees AS em', 'lr.employee_id', '=', 'em.id')
            ->where('lr.leave_status', 4)
            ->where('lr.company_id', $userCompany)
            ->whereBetween('lr.commencement_date', [$from, $to])
            ->select('em.employee_code', DB::raw("CONCAT(em.first_name,' ',em.last_name) as full_name"), 'lr.commencement_date', 'lr.resumption_date', 'lr.no_of_days', 'lt.leave_type_name')
            ->get();

        return view('report.leave_reports.hr_leave_taken_by_date_report', [
            'searchReports' => $searchReports,
            'from' => $from,
            'to' => $to
        ]);
    }
}
```

blade

```php
<input type="text" value="{{$from}}" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" readonly autocomplete="off" name="from" class="form-control fromDate">

<input type="text" value="{{$to}}" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" readonly autocomplete="off" name="to" class="form-control fromDate">
```

Comment: I  got this new Undefined variable: from.  It points to this value="{{$from}}" in the view blade.    I am using the same controller function to search and PDF Export.  I have updated my Controller and View codes. and also the route. How do I resolve this?

Comment: @SatendraRawal -  I  got this new error: Undefined variable: from.  It points to this value="{{$from}}" in the view blade.    I am using the same controller function to search and PDF Export.  I have updated my Controller and View codes. and also the route. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Can you share the blade file name?  you must be using multiple right?

Comment: @SatendraRawal -  This is the blade file name:  leaveReport and it's in a folder called reports. Which makes it:    reports.leaveReport

Answer (score 0):

You may pass `$from` and `$to` back along with `$searchReports`

```
return view('report.leave_reports.hr_leave_taken_by_date_report', [
    'searchReports' => $searchReports,
    'from' => $from,
    'to' => $to
]);
```

And assign them in the input

```
<input type="text" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" readonly autocomplete="off" name="from" class="form-control fromDate" value="{{ $from }}">
```

In case `$from` and `$to` are optional, you can add `when()` to the query

```
->when($from && $to, function($query) use ($from, $to) {
    $query->whereBetween('lr.commencement_date', [$from, $to])
})
```